# How to add Angular animations to components?

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I am using Angular 4, I have two components, a nested component (parent-child), simply imagine my child component name is **`child`**, and obviously I can import my child to its parent view by using `<app-child>` HTML element.

I have an animation and when I add the animation to  it's not working, but when I move animations into the child component, it's working.

---

### Example

**This animation is not working**

```
<app-child *ngFor="let item of child" [@anim-child-list]></app-child>
```

**When I move the animation and its logics to the child component, it works**, here is the `child` component:

```
<li [@anim-child-list]>
{{item.titme}}
</li>
```

**How is it possible to make a component (here `<app-child>`) animate?**

Comment: We would need to see either a Plunkr, or the code for your component/animation in order to better help here.

Comment: @MichaelSolati Mr. Solati again :) Yes sir, I will add my code ASAP

Comment: @MichaelSolati The question seems clear for me, but a code will help to understand it better and provide a solution.

Comment: @M98 the fact that the child elements should be animated from the parent in fine with. But what is the expected animation. That's all. And yes, the code would offer better insight to that.

Comment: Have the same issue right now.. did you ever solve it?

Comment: @Mackelito Nope! Do you have any idea?

Comment: I solved it by putting the animation on the child and then pass state as a @Input() state;

Comment: @Mackelito Thanks for sharing it! Awesome way